# Value of MutableState inside Modifier.pointerInput doesn't change after remember keys updated

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition, android-jetpack-compose-gesture

I have an offset value that is calculated or reset as

```
var offset by remember(key1 = contentScale, key2 = imageBitmap) {
    mutableStateOf(Offset.Unspecified)
}
```

This is basically a color detector from an `Image` but when `ContentScale` of the custom `Image` I wrote or `ImageBitmap` changes I want to reset it to `Offset.Unspecified` so it doesn't draw markers outside of area that is image being drawn, the grey area in gif.

[image]

This is simplified but reproducible code, I
use `Jetpack Compose 1.2.0-beta01`

```
@Composable
fun ImageColorDetector(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    imageBitmap: ImageBitmap,
    contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
    onColorChange: (ColorData) -> Unit
) {

    var offset by remember(key1 = contentScale, key2 = imageBitmap) {
        mutableStateOf(Offset.Unspecified)
    }

    println(
        "✊ImageColorDetector() imageBitmap: $imageBitmap\n" +
                "bitmap: ${imageBitmap.asAndroidBitmap()}\n" +
                "width: ${imageBitmap.width}, height: ${imageBitmap.height}\n" +
                "offset: $offset\n" +
                "contentScale: $contentScale\n\n"
    )

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                    offset = change.position
                    println("onTouchEvent:  offset: $offset")
                }
            }
    ) {
        Image(
            bitmap = imageBitmap,
            contentScale = contentScale,
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
    Text("Offset: $offset")
}
```

In `detectDragGestures` I see that offset is updated on drag gesture and when `ImageBitmap` or `ContentScale` changes, I saw in parent and this composable that they are not the same instances, so `remember` should be recalculate with new keys but it doesn't seem to work.

```
I/System.out: ⛺️ ImageColorDetectionDemo  imageBitmap: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidImageBitmap@5552c68
I/System.out: bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap@93bc881
I/System.out: width: 236, height: 394
I/System.out: contentScale: androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale$Companion$Crop$1@3226649
I/System.out: 
I/System.out: ✊ImageColorDetector() imageBitmap: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidImageBitmap@5552c68
I/System.out: bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap@93bc881
I/System.out: width: 236, height: 394
I/System.out: offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
I/System.out: contentScale: androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale$Companion$Crop$1@3226649
I/System.out: 
I/System.out: ⛺️ ImageColorDetectionDemo  imageBitmap: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidImageBitmap@7607f98
I/System.out: bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap@286d3f1
I/System.out: width: 736, height: 920
I/System.out: contentScale: androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale$Companion$Crop$1@3226649
I/System.out: 
I/System.out: ✊ImageColorDetector() imageBitmap: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidImageBitmap@7607f98
I/System.out: bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap@286d3f1
I/System.out: width: 736, height: 920
I/System.out: offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
I/System.out: contentScale: androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale$Companion$Crop$1@3226649
```

`ContentScale` is from default image code; each is an `Object`, so changing from `Crop` to `Fit` means a `key` is set.

Comment: I assume you are using a `MutableState<CropScale>` object to pass as the `contentScale` parameter, yes?

Comment: If so, have you tried passing `contentScale.hashCode()` as the key instead of the object itself? I've seen Compose struggle with non-primitives in its early days.

Comment: Yes, i checked the `contentScale.hashCode()` each change they are actually new ones and figure out the solution. It's related to `pointerInput ` creating a block with the initial values and not updating it but i can't figure out why it needs them only when remember has keys. Adding exact keys makes sure that offset triggers a recomposition.

Comment: Well you haven't posted the `pointerInput` code to be fair, so it's a bit hard to assist/clarify on that.

Comment: `pointerInput` is standard compose gesture code. I posted in question  but i am still trying to figure few things out that's why i didn't posted an answer.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't realise you actually had posted the code for the input. Sorry for the confusion. I do know what `pointerInput` is, of course, you shared all those tutorials in a question I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed

```
modifier
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
            offset = change.position
            println("onTouchEvent:  offset: $offset")
        }
    }
```

to

```
modifier
    .pointerInput(contentScale, imageBitmap) {
        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
            offset = change.position
            println("onTouchEvent:  offset: $offset")
        }
    }
```

> When a [pointerInput] modifier is created by composition, if
> [block] captures any local variables to operate on, two patterns
> are common for working with changes to those variables  depending on the desired behavior.
> Specifying the captured value as a
> [key][key1] parameter will cause [block] to cancel and restart from
> the beginning if the value changes:

Modifier.pointerInput holds to previous `MutableState` instance while new instance of `MutableState` is created when any remember keys change and  Modifier.pointerInput has no way accessing. It still hold previous instance and gesture loop runs with old MutableState with no updates.Restarting pointerInput with keys makes sure of the latest `MutableState` is read.

Comment: What do you mean when "size changes, it resets". You mean `remember` is dependent on `size`? But that doesn't make sense because size is `wrapped` inside it, it is the one job `remember` does, is to preserve the wrapped value in memory. Was that a typing error @Thracian?