# Composable not recomposing on Android API 26 (Oreo) after changing the value of a MutableState

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition, android-jetpack-compose-gesture

When I run the code present at the end of the question on devices with different Android API levels, the app behaves differently.

**Device 1: Android API 33 (Android 13)**
The code works as expected. The value of `camera2D` is changed and the composable is recomposed.

**Device 2: Android API 26 (Android Oreo)**
The code does not work as expected. The value of `camera2D` is changed but the composable is **NOT** recomposed.

Code:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.awaitEachGesture
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.awaitFirstDown
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.calculatePan
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.calculateZoom
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraints
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.withTransform
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun EditorScreen() {
    BoxWithConstraints {
        val dpToPxRatio = with(LocalDensity.current) {
            1.dp.toPx()
        }

        val camera2D = remember(key1 = maxWidth, key2 = maxHeight) {
            mutableStateOf(
                Camera2D(
                    translation = Translation2D(
                        x = (maxWidth.value * dpToPxRatio) / 2f,
                        y = (maxHeight.value * dpToPxRatio) / 2f
                    ),
                    scale = Scale2D(
                        scaleX = 1f,
                        scaleY = 1f
                    )
                )
            )
        }

        val editorObjects = remember {
            mutableStateListOf(
                SquareEditorObject2D(
                    translation = Translation2D(x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f),
                    size = Size2D(width = 350.0f, height = 580.0f),
                    scale = Scale2D(scaleX = 1.0f, scaleY = 1.0f),
                    rotation = Rotation2D(zRotationDegrees = 0f),
                    color = Color.Blue
                ),
                SquareEditorObject2D(
                    translation = Translation2D(x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f),
                    size = Size2D(width = 350.0f, height = 580.0f),
                    scale = Scale2D(scaleX = 1.0f, scaleY = 1.0f),
                    rotation = Rotation2D(zRotationDegrees = 45f),
                    color = Color.Green
                ),
                SquareEditorObject2D(
                    translation = Translation2D(x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f),
                    size = Size2D(width = 350.0f, height = 580.0f),
                    scale = Scale2D(scaleX = 1.0f, scaleY = 1.0f),
                    rotation = Rotation2D(zRotationDegrees = 135f),
                    color = Color.Red
                )
            )
        }
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .pointerInput(key1 = Unit) {
                    awaitEachGesture {
                        awaitFirstDown()

                        do {
                            val currentCamera2D = camera2D.value

                            val event = awaitPointerEvent()
                            val pointerCount = event.changes.count()
                            if (pointerCount == 1) {
                                val dragAmount = event.calculatePan()

                                camera2D.value = currentCamera2D.copy(
                                    translation = Translation2D(
                                        x = currentCamera2D.translation.x + dragAmount.x,
                                        y = currentCamera2D.translation.y + dragAmount.y
                                    )
                                )
                            } else if (pointerCount > 1) {
                                val eventZoom = event.calculateZoom()

                                camera2D.value = currentCamera2D.copy(
                                    scale = Scale2D(
                                        scaleX = currentCamera2D.scale.scaleX * eventZoom,
                                        scaleY = currentCamera2D.scale.scaleY * eventZoom
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })
                    }
                }
        ) {
            withTransform(
                {
                    translate(
                        left = camera2D.value.translation.x,
                        top = camera2D.value.translation.y
                    )
                    scale(
                        scaleX = camera2D.value.scale.scaleX,
                        scaleY = camera2D.value.scale.scaleY
                    )
                }
            ) {
                for (editorObject in editorObjects) {
                    withTransform(
                        {
                            translate(
                                left = editorObject.translation.x - editorObject.pivot.x,
                                top = editorObject.translation.y - editorObject.pivot.y
                            )
                            rotate(
                                degrees = editorObject.rotation.zRotationDegrees,
                                pivot = Offset(
                                    x = editorObject.size.width / 2f,
                                    y = editorObject.size.height / 2f
                                )
                            )
                            scale(
                                scaleX = editorObject.scale.scaleX,
                                scaleY = editorObject.scale.scaleY,
                                pivot = Offset(
                                    x = editorObject.size.width / 2f,
                                    y = editorObject.size.height / 2f
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    ) {
                        drawRect(
                            color = editorObject.color,
                            size = Size(
                                width = editorObject.size.width,
                                height = editorObject.size.height
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

data class Translation2D(val x: Float, val y: Float)

data class Size2D(val width: Float, val height: Float)

data class Scale2D(val scaleX: Float, val scaleY: Float)

data class Rotation2D(val zRotationDegrees: Float)

data class SquareEditorObject2D(
    val translation: Translation2D = Translation2D(x = 0f, y = 0f),
    val size: Size2D,
    val scale: Scale2D = Scale2D(scaleX = 1f, scaleY = 1f),
    val rotation: Rotation2D = Rotation2D(zRotationDegrees = 0f),
    val color: Color
) {

    val pivot = Translation2D(
        x = (size.width / 2f),
        y = (size.height / 2f)
    )
}

data class Camera2D(
    val translation: Translation2D = Translation2D(x = 0f, y = 0f),
    val scale: Scale2D = Scale2D(scaleX = 1f, scaleY = 1f),
    val rotation: Rotation2D = Rotation2D(zRotationDegrees = 0f)
)
```

Libraries Versions:

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happens when closures capture a `State` and when you create new instance of that `State` new one is not passed to closure.

```
 val camera2D = remember(key1 = maxWidth, key2 = maxHeight) {
            mutableStateOf(
                Camera2D(
                    translation = Translation2D(
                        x = (maxWidth.value * dpToPxRatio) / 2f,
                        y = (maxHeight.value * dpToPxRatio) / 2f
                    ),
                    scale = Scale2D(
                        scaleX = 1f,
                        scaleY = 1f
                    )
                )
            )
        }
```

Creates new instance of `MutableState` but previous instance exists inside `pointerInput`.

You need to set same keys to `pointerInput(key1 = maxWidth, key2 = maxHeight)` to reset it so it will capture the current `MutableState` assigned to `camera2D` after remember is reset.

Explained in detail how `LaunchedEffect`, `DisposableEffect` or  which both are `remember` under the hood, or `pointerInput` capture a `State` and don't get new one unless you reset these with `keys`.

[Value of MutableState inside Modifier.pointerInput doesn't change after remember keys updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72299963/value-of-mutablestate-inside-modifier-pointerinput-doesnt-change-after-remember)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73610519/5457853

Also check last part of this answer where you can see new instance is not stored inside lambda of LaunchedEffect.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77321291/5457853

Comment: Thank you very much for the contribution @Thracian. It worked perfectly! I just didn't understand why it worked on API 33 but not on API 26.

Comment: It shouldn't work with any version. It never worked form me if i don't update keys of `pointerInput`